# Правильно ли составлено предложение по смыслу? если нет, то как правильно?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

"Люди принимали участие в транспортировке бревен из леса к дороге"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Про бревна - это я так.. Вот сами предложения: " Некоторые из гражданских лиц, так же содействовали в поиске пропавших в лесу людей и принимали непосредственное участие в транспортировке  тел из леса к дороге"  Подскажите как правильно сформулировать предложения - если не правильно!

Comment: @user201552 Некоторые из гражданских лиц также содействовали поиску пропавших в лесу людей и непосредственно участвовали в транспортировке тел из леса к дороге.

Comment: Спасибо огромное вам!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По смыслу верно. Но можно избавиться от канцеляритности — вместо *принимали участие* достаточно сказать: *участвовали*.

Comment: По смыслу обычно все бывает понятно. "А транспортировка тел" — это правильно? Можно ли такое сочетание считать стилистической ошибкой?

Comment: @Sharon это звучит сухо, но вряд ли можно считать ошибкой.

Comment: А я считаю такое сочетание оскорбительным по отношению к людям. Так что здесь ваш канцелярит выходит за разумные пределы.

Comment: @Sharon "транспортировка тела" — обычное название услуги в морге. Например, когда на отпевание в храм отвозят и потом на кладбище.

Comment: Там свои понятия об этике.  А почему вы убрали "непосредственное участие", может, здесь есть какой-то дополнительный смысл?

Comment: @Sharon я заменил "принимали непосредственное участие" на "непосредственно участвовали". Смысл тот же, а звучит без лишнего слова лучше.